# How to get list using for loop in python and we have to capitalize the first letter of the every element?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

You are given a list of string elements and asked to return a list which contains each element of the string in title case or in other words first character of the string would be in upper case and remaining all characters in lower case

Sample Input:

```
['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
```

Sample Output

```
['Varma', 'Raj', 'Gupta', 'Sandeep']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`capitalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) method of `string` and list comprehension as followings:

```
data = ['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']

capitalized = [a.capitalize() for a in data]

print(capitalized)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
updated_list= []

for i in input_list:
    updated_list.append(i.capitalize())
    
print(updated_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. It would also be useful to differentiate it from the other six answers; why might someone prefer your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Using [str.title()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

```
a = ['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
res = [x.title() for x in a]
print(res)
#['Varma', 'Raj', 'Gupta', 'Sandeep']
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Harun is probably the best one here, but as an alternative, and a more general answer, we can consider using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```
data = ['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
capitalized = [re.sub(r'^(.)(.*)$', lambda m: m.group(1).upper() + m.group(2).lower(), a)
    for a in data]
print(capitalized)
```

This prints:

```
['Varma', 'Raj', 'Gupta', 'Sandeep']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lt = ['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
```

Using **Map** Function

```
print(list(map(lambda x : x.title(),lt)))
Output - ['Varma', 'Raj', 'Gupta', 'Sandeep']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `capitalize()` method of string and list comprehension as followings:

```
data = [ ' Verma' ,  ' raj ' ,  ' Gupta ' ,  ' SaNdeeP ' ]
capitalized = [ a.capitalize( )  for a in data ]
print ( capitalized )
```

Comment: @upGrad team check my answer I am not able to proceed into the next session

Answer (score 0):

### Below code is working fine !

```
input_list = ['VARMA', 'raj', 'Gupta', 'SaNdeeP']
output=[] 
for i in range(len(input_list)): # length of input 
    output.append(input_list[i][0].upper() + input_list[i][1:].lower()) # first character as uppercase and remaining characters a lower case
print(output)
```

Output

['Varma', 'Raj', 'Gupta', 'Sandeep']